# RQ - Empty & Delete Queues

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I'm using [RQ](http://python-rq.org/), and I have a `failed` queue with thousands of items, and another `test` queue I created a while back for testing which is now empty and unused. I'm wondering how to remove all jobs from the `failed` queue, and delete the `test` queue altogether?

Apologies for the basic question, but I can't find info on this in the [RQ docs](http://python-rq.org/docs/), and I'm completely new to both [Redis](http://redis.io/) and RQ... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Cleanup using rq

RQ offers methods to make any queue empty:

```
>>> from redis import Redis
>>> from rq import Queue
>>> qfail = Queue("failed", connection=Redis())
>>> qfail.count
8
>>> qfail.empty()
8L
>>> qfail.count
0
```

You can do the same for `test` queue, if you have it still present.

## Cleanup using `rq-dashboard`

Install rq-dashboard:

```
$ pip install rq-dashboard
```

Start it:

```
$ rq-dashboard
RQ Dashboard, version 0.3.4
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:9181/
```

Open in browser.

Select the queue

Click the red button "Empty"

And you are done.

## Python function Purge jobs

If you run too old Redis, which fails on command used by RQ, you still might sucess with deleting
jobs by python code:

The code takes a name of a queue, where are job ids.

Usilg LPOP we ask for job ids by one.

Adding prefix (by default "rq:job:") to job id we have a key, where is job stored.

Using DEL on each key we purge our database job by job.

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis()
>>> qname = "rq:queue:failed"
>>> def purgeq(r, qname):
...   while True:
...     jid = r.lpop(qname)
...     if jid is None:
...         break
...     r.delete("rq:job:" + jid)
...     print(jid)
...
>>> purge(r, qname)
a0be3624-86c1-4dc4-bb2e-2043d2734b7b
3796c312-9b02-4a77-be89-249aa7325c25
ca65f2b8-044c-41b5-b5ac-cefd56699758
896f70a7-9a35-4f6b-b122-a08513022bc5
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply. From your answer, I tried using `redis-cli` with `del` and using Redis from Python. Unfortunately listing keys in either methods appears to be listing jobs, not the queues, attempting to delete the queues through these methods doesn't work (I get 0 returned each time)?

Comment: @Cian I rewrote the answer to use `rq` library and optionally `rq-dashboard`

Comment: Thanks Jan, I really appreciate your input. Using rq I get the error `redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'EVALSHA'` when I call `qfail.empty()`?

Comment: @Cian What version of Redis do you have? EVALSHA is present since 2.6.0, I have version 2.8.6.

Comment: I'm on version 2.2 - is there a way to delete jobs and queues compatible with v2.2?

Comment: @Clan I put back into my question the purging function `purgeq`, which shall work. Try it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that Jan. I had just deleted the failed queue, but that solution there is nice and concise. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 13):

## - 2016 -

You can now use rq's `empty` option form command line:

```
/path/to/rq empty queue_name
```

So you can use it to empty any queue not just the failed one

Comment: I tried `$ rq empty default --config myproject.config
Error: no such option: --config`

Comment: What happened if you don't use the config flag? What RQ version do you have?

Comment: without config flag everything works as expected. Version 0.7.1

Answer (score 4):

none of the above solutions worked
failed Queue is not registered under queues

so I move all of the failed jobs to default Queue and use

> rq empty queue_name --url [redis-url]

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to clear the failed job registry using `django_rq`:

```py
import django_rq
from rq.registry import FailedJobRegistry

queue = django_rq.get_queue("your_queue_with_failed_jobs")
registry = FailedJobRegistry(queue=queue)

for job_id in registry.get_job_ids():
  registry.remove(job_id)
```

Comment: Worked well for me in March 2023

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring tool `rqinfo` can empty failed queue.
Just make sure you have an active virtualenv with `rq` installed, and run

`$ rqinfo --empty-failed-queue`

See `rqinfo --help` for more details.

Comment: This option no longer available.  I'm on RQ 0.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

you can just login to redis and clear all queues

to login

> user@user:~$ **redis-cli**

enter this command and hit enter

> **FLUSHALL**

And you're done

> Edit: **This will delete everything stored in redis**

Comment: this would, of course, delete EVERYTHING from redis, and not just the RQ queues. so not a great answer.

Comment: @FuzzyAmi Yes, you are absolutely right.
I must have mentioned that, I  will add that information

Answer (score 1):

**- 2022 -**

I was struggling with this as well and this is a piece of code which works for me.

It loops over queues name (in my case, 'default' and 'low'), fetch all failed jobs for each queue and remove them

```
import django_rq
from rq.registry import FailedJobRegistry
from redis import Redis
from rq.job import Job
from django.conf import settings
redis = Redis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST, port=settings.REDIS_PORT)
queues = ["default", "low"]
for q in queues:
    queue = django_rq.get_queue(q)
    registry = FailedJobRegistry(queue=queue)
    for job_id in registry.get_job_ids():
        job = Job.fetch(job_id, connection=redis)
        registry.remove(job)
```

Answer (score -1):

By default 'rq' jobs are prefixed by 'rq:job'. So you can delete these jobs from the redis using following command,

```
redis-cli KEYS rq:job:* | xargs redis-cli DEL
```