# Delete a Queue from Python-RQ / Redis

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I'm using Python RQ (backed by Redis) to feed tasks to a bunch of worker processes.

I accidentally sent a tuple when adding a job to a queue, so now I have queues like this:

```
high
medium
low
('low',)
default
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the `('low',)` queue.  The queue also seems to cause some issues due to its name (for instance, I couldn't view it or clear it in rq-dashboard as the page would refuse to load).

There is some discussion here: [RQ - Empty & Delete Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915181/rq-empty-delete-queues), but that only covers emptying a queue.  I am able to empty the queue just fine from within Python, but I can't seem to actually delete the queue from the Redis server.

The RQ documentation doesn't seem to provide any information on getting rid of a queue you don't want.

I want to actually delete that queue (not just empty it) instead of carrying it around forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RQ stores all the queues under rq:queues keys. This can be accessed by the redis-cli.

```
smembers rq:queues
```

I also stumbled upon [Destroying / removing a Queue() in Redis Queue (rq) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129509/destroying-removing-a-queue-in-redis-queue-rq-programmatically?rq=1) This might help!

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do it with `SREM rq:queues "rq:queue:('low',)"`,  Queue was already empty--not sure what would happen if I tried to remove a queue that still had jobs in it.

Comment: You may integrate rq-dashboard, it can help you monitor your jobs and it also provides feature to delete queues or jobs.